# What is the meaning of using a past participle after 'of'?

Tags: meaning, past-participles

I'm reading The Go-Giver.

There is a sentence:

> Now some character he'd never heard of had underbid and outperformed
>   him.

I expected after *of* in above sentence will be *V-ing*, but the author was using V3 (the past participle) I think. What is the special English structure or meaning here?

Comment: The 'of' from the sentence is actually part of the object, which is "some character he'd never heard of". The writer was explaining what the object had made him feel therefore he used V3. If the writer was explaining what the object is making him feel, he will use V-ing.

Comment: Why do you expect a V-ing?

Comment: Now some character - he had never heard of - had underbid and outperformed him.  - You have "character + a normal past perfect: had underbid ... him"

Comment: What do you call it a V3?

Comment: @curiousdannii Some grammarians (especially in the language teaching world) prefer V3 because 'past participle's don't have anything to do with the past :)

Comment: @curiousdannii Maybe we need a glossary on here!

Comment: I would understand v3 as third verb form of the three base forms as in write/wrote/written.

Comment: "Never heard of" is an idiom that stands alone.  You can read it as "of whom he had never heard", if you insist that one must never use a preposition to end a sentence with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Prepositions and *-ing* forms:**

Many prepositions take noun phrases as Complements, for example the preposition *of*:

- I'm scared of **spiders**.

In the sentence above, we see the noun phrase *spiders* occurring as the Complement of the preposition. When we want to use a verb (technically a clause) as the Complement of a preposition like *of*, we need to use an *-ing* form of the verb ( a gerund-participle):

- I'm scared of **flying**.

So here we see the *-ing* form of the verb *fly* occurring after the preposition *of*.

The fact above leads many teachers and grammar books to tell readers that:

- **1.** **We need to use an *-ing* form of the verb after a preposition.**

Of course, this rule is not clear enough. I mentioned above that in sentences like these we should really think about the bit after the preposition as being a clause not just a verb. If we give the verb an overt Subject, this will be clearer:

- I'm tired of Bob getting all the best jobs.

Here we see the clause *Bob getting all the best jobs* occurring after the preposition *of*. Notice that this is a clause headed by the *ing* form of the verb *GET*. So in this example, the verb *getting* is not occurring after the preposition. What we see is a clause after the preposition *of*, and this *clause* must use an *-ing* form of the verb.

So, maybe we need to reformulate this rule. Perhaps we could say:

- **2. When we want to use a clause after a preposition, we need to use a clause headed by an *-ing* form.**

Assuming that we are talking just about prepositions which usually take noun phrases as Complements, is the rule above ok? The answer is no! The rule in (2) is missing the important word *Complement* (some grammars use the term *Object*). Just because a verb or clause appears after a preposition, it does not mean that that verb/clause is the Complement of the preposition. Consider the following example:

- The spider you are scared of died.

In the sentence above, we see the verb *died* occurring after the preposition *of*. However, this verb is not the Complement of the preposition. The word *of* is part of a relative clause. This relative clause is part of the Subject. We can model the sentence like this:

- [The spider (that) you are scared of] died.

In the model above we can see that the Subject consists of a noun phrase *the spider* modified by a relative clause *(that) you are scared of*. The word *that* is optional here. So, if *died* is not the Complement of the preposition *of*, what exactly is the Complement of this preposition? The answer is that the Complement of the preposition is a gap. We understand the gap to refer to the spider. We can model the sentence like this:

- The spider that [you are scared of <s>him</s>] died.
- The spider<sub>(i)</sub> that [you are scared of __<sub>(i)</sub>] died.

In the sentence above, the verb *died* is the verb in the main clause. It is not the Complement of the preposition *of* and therefore it does not need to be an *-ing* form of the verb. We need to reformulate our rule like this:

- **3. When we want to use a clause as the Complement of a preposition, we need to use a clause headed by an *-ing* form.**

### **The Original Poster's example**

> Now some character he'd never heard of had underbid and outperformed him.

We can remove the word *now* here, it is not important for the grammar of the sentence. This give us:

- Some character he'd never heard of had underbid and outperformed him.

This sentence has a relative clause where the word *that* (or *whom*) has been omitted. If we take out the relative clause, the sentence looks like this:

- Some character had underbid and outperformed him.

In the sentence above we can see that the verb phrase uses a past perfect construction *had underbid and outperformed*. The past perfect is just used to show that the underbidding and outperforming happened before the time we are thinking about. The past perfect construction is just part of the normal tense usage within the sentence.

The preposition *of* in the example, has a gap as a Complement. This gap refers to *some character*:

- **Some character [he'd never heard of <s>that character</s>]** had underbid and outperformed him.

This relative clause is part of the Subject of the larger sentence— in bold above. We can see from the example that even though the verb phrase "*had underbid and outperformed ...*" occurs directly after the preposition *of*, it is not a Complement of that preposition. Because of this, we do not need to use an *-ing* form of the verb. The fact that the verb uses a past perfect construction is unrelated to the preposition. It's just the normal use of verb forms within the larger sentence.

Comment: *The answer is that we Complement of the preposition is a gap.*  Probably *we* should be *the*.  *where the word ?that (or whom) has been omitted.* Probably the question mark is a typo.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks very much! Had gone text-blind ..

Comment: I figured.  If I contribute nothing else, at least I can provide a little proofreading of your excellent answers.

Comment: The entire first half of the answer has nothing to do with the example sentence, and is misleading, suggesting that the original post’s misparsing is accurate (it isn’t). The *of* and *had underbid* have nothing to do with one another, they are in separate clauses.

Comment: @KRyan Huh? The point is that many books tell users to use *-ing* forms after prepositions. The main point in my answer is that the clause occurring after the preposition is not part of that PP. I don't understand what you're aiming at??

Comment: The question already brings up the expectation of a *-ing* form after *of*, rehashing “rules” that the OP is already familiar with is redundant, but more importantly *misleading*, because it suggests that there is something to the OP’s expectation here. There isn’t. Absolutely none of that explanation about *-ing* forms applies in any way to the example sentence, and having to read an entire page (and then some) before getting to “but none of that has anything to do with this example” is not a good answer.

Comment: @KRyan If you vaguely know a rule and misunderstand it and it is leading you to misunderstand a sentence, then fully understanding the rule and how it doesn't apply to your sentence is the main issue. Please feel free to write a better answer. I'll certainly upvote it, if it's helpful.

Comment: You should answer the question *asked*, or at the very least answer the question asked *first*, before adding extraneous information that you think the OP might want to also know.

Comment: @KRyan The first part of their question stiplulates the V-ing after prep. That's the bit I answered first. As I said feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @KRyan From the words of the OP, it's likely that he had an expectation of finding a gerund after *of* and was surprised to find a past participle.  His confusion would seem to arise not from the "rule" but from trying to parse the sentence lexically (or linearly, if you prefer) and not structurally.  Araucaria's explanation is a step-by-step explanation of what the rule means in the context of proper parsing.  This may be too detailed for you, but a dozen people have upvoted it.  You may want to reread the answer because "none of that has anything to do with this..." doesn't appear there.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. But if the sentence were better punctuated you would understand more clearly what has happened.

Had I written it, I would have put parenthetical commas around ***he'd never heard of***.

In other words the *of* is not operating in conjunction with the verb which follows, but forms part of the previous clause.

Some might argue that it should have said: ***of whom he'd never heard***, and they could be regarded as having a point. Some of the more literate class in Britain, would have said that. And it would have been better English, in my view.

But since it is perfectly idiomatic to put prepositions at the ends of phrases, and most people do it every day, the sentence should be regarded as correct as it stands. But the punctuation is lacking.

Comment: If you were going to put parenthetical commas around it then **of whom he'd never heard** would be better. As it stands, 'he'd never of heard of' sounds odd as a standalone statement.

Comment: It is subjective, I know, but barenthetical commas would be a bit weird, as "some character he had never heard of" is functioning as a single element that could be replaced by, for example, "Bob". If you put "that" in front of it and then seperated it out with commas - that might work": 'some character, that he had never heard of, had outbid..."

Comment: @SGR I agree. *Of whom he'd never heard* is better all round, in my view. There is a very good reason why a rule once existed about not ending phrases with prepositions, i.e. clarity. And this sentence is a very good example of why not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`some character he'd never heard of` is the subject of the sentence.

It is certainly reduced from

> Now some character **that** he'd never heard of *had underbid and outperformed him.*

<del>`Hear of` is a phrasal verb which also means `agree, obey, accept`</del>

Comment: I'm a native speaker and have never seen that usage of `hear of` to mean `agree, obey, accept.` To hear of someone is to hear that person being talked about, or in more general terms, to become aware of that person's existence.

Comment: @Level River St   "I won't hear of it!"  is an old, probably obsolete, British idiomatic meaning.

Comment: @AlMaki Yes that does make sense to me and sound slightly familiar, but it can only be used in the negative. It's also barely a phrasal verb, as the original non-idiomatic meaning is "If you do that, I don't want to hear about it."